# Bubble box instead of alert box

Tags: android

Currently in my map, i allows the user to pin point anywhere on the map and i have this **alert dialog box** which shows the user the map's location. But i don't want it to be alert dialog box, i want it to be like a **bubble box** and beside the bubble box there's a arrow which i can click on the arrow to fetch the location back to another activity. Any idea?

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowMaps.this)
                        .setTitle(add)
                        .setMessage("Go to the new location?")
                        .setNegativeButton("No",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int which) {
                                    }
                                }).show();
```

But i don't want it to be alert dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html).

Comment: can you do an example for me to see?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use ItemizedOverlay ?

Comment: What has bubble box gotta do with itemizedoverlay?

Comment: You can refer to one of my previous posts for elements of answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359050/using-mutliple-drawables-on-a-mapview/8359424#8359424